# How to generate log in cvs containing the diffrence of revision

Tags: repository, cvs

I am using the CVS repository and using CVS diff but in diff I can see only the the modified file but I want who did these changes.

So I want the difference and the name of author who make changes on this revision in a same log file.

Is there any available command in CVS to do that?

Comment: `cvs diff` shows the differences between your working copy and the CVS repository. So the person who made the changes is *you*. I'm guessing this isn't actually what you are asking. Can you clarify, maybe with an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the authoring information (who committed the file) that's

```
cvs log <filename>
```

This will give you each revision, the author, added lines, etc